# built libbost.a with gcc 4.1.2 and can't use with gcc 4.8.2

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I have created a shared library(libTest.so) with statically linking with boost. boost library and libTest.so are built with gcc-4.1.2.

I have a need where main program is built with gcc-4.8.2, linking dynamically with libTest.so and uses same gcc run time.

I get "Segmentation fault" when main program loads the libTest.so file

Some one said that not to use libboost( which is built with 4.1.2 ) with main program which built with gcc 4.8.2

Workaround: LD_PRELOAD of libTest.so I did not get any segmentation faults.

Please help me in fixing this issue???

Comment: Which part of Boost library do you need? Which version of Boost are you using? Most of it is header only! And indeed you can't mix code compiled with `g++` 4.1.2 (a very ancient and buggy version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), which is much older than the C++11 standard) with code compiled with `g++` 4.8.2. If needed, compile a recent [boost](http://www.boost.org/) 1.56 with your `g++` 4.8.2

Comment: I am using date-time, python, regex and serialization of boost and boost version is 1.49.

You mean there is no other way except building boost, libTest with GCC-4.8.2..???

Comment: Probably no other *reliable* way, and I don't feel it is worth even trying. Building boost from source code takes a lot of CPU time, but should not take a lot of *your* human time.

Comment: Thanks Basile.. n i'll start building boost with gcc-4.8.2.

Comment: But then build a recent version of Boost